# Wrong name resolution when parent and inner class have the same name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2003, class-hierarchy, token-name-resolution

I have an odd case with Visual Studio 2003. For somewhat legitimate reasons, I have the following hierarchy:

```
class A {};

class B : public A {
public:
    class A {};
};

class C : public B::A {};
```

That is, I have an inner class with the same name as a parent of the outer class. When `C` tries to inherit from `B::A`, Visual Studio thinks I'm pointing to the parent class `A`, not the nested class within `B`. GCC seems to resolve to the inner class version as I expected

Is this a Visual Studio 2003 bug, or am I doing it wrong? Is there a workaround (other than upgrading Visual Studio)?

Comment: Visual C++ 2003 was released nine years ago.  It would be advisable to upgrade for a great many reasons.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis If I were in charge of these things we would have upgraded a long time ago, but sadly I'm not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this looks like VS2003 bug. Workaround is simple - use typedef, it works this way:

```
class A { public: int x; };
class B : public A { public: class A { public: int y; }; }; 

typedef B::A BA;

class C: public BA {};

void f()
{
   C cc;
   cc.y = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a bug in Visual C++ 2003.  Using Visual C++ 2012, `B::A` correctly names the nested class `A`, not the base class `A`.

Comment: As for a workaround, I don't know:  the design is rather questionable.  I would rename the nested class.  If I had Visual C++ 2003 installed I'd try to see what's up, but I haven't used Visual C++ 2003 in a few years.

Comment: I was stupid and didn't test my simplified example; turns out it was wrong. The updated one reproduces the problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a VS bug,
I didn't know Thanks for posting.
I think The workaround will be a `SafeInherit` Template I don't know what will be a better name.

```
template <typename T>
struct SafeInherit{
  typedef T Type;
};

class B : public SafeInherit<A>::Type {
  public:
  class A {};
}
```